# java - multiple http requests at same time With multi threading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm calling multiple request(10) at same time HTTP GET method.Here calling method will create different threads (Like Thread 1,Thread 2 ....)

Caller Method:

```
enter code here: for(int i=0;i<10;i++){Thread.currentThread().getId();HttpClient httpClient = new HtpClient(url);res = httpClient.get(5000);}
```

Then Request will hit application entry point.The entry point will create new threads for each and every request  (Like Thread 11,Thread 12 ....).

```
enter code here//public void DoProcess(){Thread.currentThread().getId();// New threads for each request.else........}
```

But i want to know which caller thread request created application thread.

Like Thread 1 belongs Thread 11

```
 Thread 2 belongs Thread 12
```

Please let me know,how to achieved this.

Comment: When thread 1 creates thread 11, you pass a reference of thread 1 to thread 11.

Answer (score 0):

Client connects through TCP, so there is a socket client ip and port involved.
I don't know HTTPClient api by heart but if there is a getClientPort() then you should be able to printout the time, thread name and client ip+port. On the server, whatever accept the socket will have the client ip and port too. If this is a servlet container, the servlet request has getRemoteAddress() and getRemotePort(). There too you can print out the time, ip+port and thread name. If you pile those events in 2 tables, you should be able to join by ip+port with a tolerance on the client time vs server time (try less than 2 seconds apart, assuming C and S are on same time with NTP).

The other trivial way (but it changes the http payload) is to inject a HTTP header from the client into the http request, stating the current thread name/tid. Ex: "my_custom_remote_thread_id: Thread-11". This way on the server you can pull the request header to figure the client thread name/tid.